# get HTTP code status and retry-after, Outlook Api

Tags: php, curl, http-headers

I have this URL from which I get events from Outlook:

```
// ! API sorting by Id doesn't work so we'll have to implement it ourselves.
    $url = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users/' . $this->user . '/CalendarView/'
        . '?startDateTime=' . $start_datetime
        . '&endDateTime=' . $end_datetime
        .'&$top=100';
```

I am quite new to this and right now I am trying to get the response as below:

```
    $http = new \Http_Curl();
    $http->set_headers( $this->get_headers() );
    $response = $http->get( $url );

where I have this `HTTP_CURL` class that contains methods as below:



public function get( $url ) {
            return $this->request( $url, 'GET', $this->headers );
        }

private function request( $url, $method, $headers, $data = false ) {
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

        if ( $this->headers )
            curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headers );

        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
        curl_setopt( $handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true );

        switch ( $method ) {
            case 'POST':
                curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
                break;
            case 'PATCH':
                curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
                curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH' );
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE' );
                break;
        }

        $http_response = curl_exec( $handle );

        curl_close( $handle );

        return json_decode( $http_response );
    }
```

What I need is to get also the HTTP error code in the response.
According to Outlook The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting"). A Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.

So how do I get this HTTP error code and the Retry-After? Like this link:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429
```

I tried to ad this line:  `$httpcode = curl_error($url, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`
and I keep getting null.

Answer (score 1):

You used an invalid parameter in the [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) function. Should be `curl_error($handle)`.

The best way is to use the Guzzle PHP HTTP client. It has [methods for getting response headers](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#response-headers). You can use [this perfect example](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1806#issuecomment-293931737) to make a repeated requests:

> ```
> <?php
> require './vendor/autoload.php';
>
> use GuzzleHttp\Client;
> use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
> use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
> use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;
> use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
> use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
> use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
> use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
>
> class TestRetry {
>
>     public function test()
>     {
>         $handlerStack = HandlerStack::create(new CurlHandler());
>         $handlerStack->push(Middleware::retry($this->retryDecider(),
>         $this->retryDelay()));
>         $client = new Client(array('handler' => $handlerStack));
>
>         $response = $client->request(
>             'GET',
>             // @todo replace to a real url!!!
>             'https://500-error-code-url'
>         )->getBody()->getContents();
>
>         return \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response, true);
>     }
>
>
>     public function retryDecider()
>     {
>         return function (
>             $retries,
>             Request $request,
>             Response $response = null,
>             RequestException $exception = null
>         ) {
>             // Limit the number of retries to 5
>             if ($retries >= 5) {
>                 return false;
>             }
>
>             // Retry connection exceptions
>             if ($exception instanceof ConnectException) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>
>             if ($response) {
>                 // Retry on server errors
>                 if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 500 ) {
>                     return true;
>                 }
>             }
>
>             return false;
>         };
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * delay 1s 2s 3s 4s 5s
>      *
>      * @return Closure
>      */
>     public function retryDelay()
>     {
>         return function ($numberOfRetries) {
>             return 1000 * $numberOfRetries;
>         };
>     }
> }
>
> $TestRetry = new TestRetry();
> $TestRetry->test();
> ```

I slightly changed this code for your case:

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

class MyOutlookApiClient {

    const BASE_API_URL = 'https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0';
    public $user;
    protected $retryOnErrors;
    protected $retryMaxCount;

    /**
     * @param $user
     */
    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $retryOnErrors
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRetryOnErrors($retryOnErrors=[])
    {
        $this->retryOnErrors = $retryOnErrors;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $retryMaxCount
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setRetryMaxCount($retryMaxCount = 5)
    {
        $this->retryMaxCount = $retryMaxCount;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param $startDatetime
     * @param $endDatetime
     * @param $top
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsersCalendarView($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $top)
    {
        $handlerStack = HandlerStack::create(new CurlHandler());
        $handlerStack->push(Middleware::retry($this->retryDecider(),
            $this->retryDelay()));
        $client = new Client(array('handler' => $handlerStack));

        $calendarViewUrl = self::BASE_API_URL.'/users/'.$this->user.'/CalendarView/';
        $queryParams = [
            'startDateTime' => $startDatetime,
            'endDateTime' => $endDatetime,
            'top' => $top
        ];
        $response = $client
            ->request('GET', $calendarViewUrl, ['query' => $queryParams])
            ->getBody()
            ->getContents();

        return \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($response, true);
    }

    /**
     * @return Closure
     */
    public function retryDecider()
    {
        return function (
            $retries,
            Request $request,
            Response $response = null,
            RequestException $exception = null
        ) {
            // Limit the number of retries to 5
            if ($retries >= $this->retryMaxCount) {
                return false;
            }

            // Retry connection exceptions
            if ($exception instanceof ConnectException) {
                return true;
            }

            if ($response) {
                // Retry on server errors
                $responseCode = $response->getStatusCode();
                if (
                    ($this->retryOnErrors && in_array($responseCode, $this->retryOnErrors))
                    || ($responseCode >= 500)
                ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        };
    }

    /**
     * delay 1s 2s 3s 4s 5s
     *
     * @return Closure
     */
    public function retryDelay()
    {
        return function ($numberOfRetries) {
            return 1000 * $numberOfRetries;
        };
    }
}

// your code to init variables here
// ...

$myOutlookApiClient = new MyOutlookApiClient($user);
$myOutlookApiClient
    ->setRetryOnErrors([429])
    ->setRetryMaxCount(5)
    ->getUsersCalendarView($startDatetime, $endDatetime, $top);
```